# jsFiddle with Knockout works in IE 11 not in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, knockout.js, jsfiddle

This is an EXACT copy of the sample Hello World fiddle.  I just pasted it into a fiddle of my own and added the reference to http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.2.0.js.  It works in IE 11, but not in Chrome.  It does not appear to resolve the knockout reference.  Is there a setting or two that is special for Chrome?

> // Here's my data model var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
>       this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
>       this.lastName = ko.observable(last);
>
> ```
> this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
>     // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName depends on firstName and lastName, because these get called
> ```
>
> when evaluating fullName.
>           return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
>       }, this); };   ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth")); // This makes Knockout get to work

https://jsfiddle.net/KellyWCline/rwL4rng9/2/

Comment: Did you get the answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a security problem: for security reasons, Chrome rejects an script from an `HTTP` URL when you're inside an `HTTPS` page. Include Knockout from an `HTTPS` URL like `https://cdnjs.com/libraries/knockout/3.2.0`, and it will start working.

If you had looked at Chrome's console you would have seen this error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/KellyWCline/rwL4rng9/2/show/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.2.0.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I can assign it, and when I click on it, it goes to the cdnjs page.  But, when I run the jsfiddle (updated to /3), it still returns two errors:  the first is Unexpected token < at line 1 of the index file (the doctype.html declaration).  The second is 'ko is not defined'.